# Would Human Hair Be an Electrical Conductor or an Insulator

Tags: science-based, hair

So in my world it is the future and ALMOST ALL NATURAL METALS are gone. They needed power to get delivered in some form.
One scientist thought up a solution: Human hair.

The science community was torn as to if it would work or not. They give their reasons as to why it would, or why it wouldn't work.

Now I ask you, the community, whether it would work or not.

(I don't know the answer so this determines the outcome of this part of the story.)

Comment: I don't really think this question is worthy of an answer so I'll just comment, "no, it wouldn't be useful as either an electrical insulator or an electrical conductor".

Comment: This seems like it should be on Physic.SE, not worldbuilding.

Comment: @Bewilderer if more people say that then I will move it.

Comment: I would guess hair would work well as a very low current fuse... though possibly for values of well that don't come close to matching industry standards. That said, there are non-metallic materials that do conduct electricity reasonably well. We don't use them in practice because they're generally not as good as metal conductors and the closer they get to being as good or in some ways better than metal conductors, the more expensive they get.

Comment: If you're looking for something that could possibly work in our world, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductive_polymer

Comment: This could be easily answered with a simple multimeter. And in fact the resistance of my own hair is > 2 million ohms/cm.  (Actually infinite on that scale.)  So no, it won't work as a conductor.

Comment: Hair is an insulator. As a memorable example, rub a plastic ruler on your hair; it will become charged with static electricity due to the [triboelectric effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triboelectric_effect), which you can test by trying to attract small pieces of paper. (This experiment used to be done in physics class in primary school.) It is also easily flammable when dry and has decent strength in tension.

Comment: @Bewilderer, [real world questions are on-topic here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6161) so long as the question meets the WB.SE requirements in the [help].

Comment: First, primary world questions may be on topic here, but really only when they help us to understand how the secondary world works.  This question really does *not* do that at all. It's simply a plot generator.  Second, this is a clear case of **Let Me Google That For You**.  Third, the OP states that the question is 100% story based.  *(I don't know the answer so this determines the outcome of this part of the story.)* Three good causes for closure in my book.

Comment: @Bewilderer - I was so disappointed to find that Physic.SE was just a typo.

Comment: [Harvesting electricity from human hair - PubMed](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/27319058/)

Comment: Look at the periodic table (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Taxonomic_PT_with_colour_categories.jpg) and you'll see that there's only a handful of nonmetallic elements. Earth's crust is 46% oxygen, 28% silicon, and the remainder is almost entirely metals...largely aluminum, which works quite well as an electrical conductor. If you don't have metals, you don't have anything to produce or consume power, so what do you need conductors for?

Comment: @ChristopherJamesHuff His planet also should have a suspicious lack of life... and existence: For a physicist, mono-Hydrogen is (under many views) a metal.

Comment: @Trish hydrogen just exists as a gas at "normal" temperatures, and as a non-metallic allotrope at "normal" pressures (this isn't unique, tin has a non-metallic allotrope), it becomes quite metallic under high pressure. It might be better placed on the periodic table as a metalloid or post-transition metal. And astrophysicists have their own definition...for them, everything that's *not* hydrogen or helium is a metal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the right conditions, anything can be made to conduct electricity.  However, the value of that conduction varies greatly.

Naturally (as @AlexP) states) hair is an insulator.  A very high frequency, very low amperage signal could be sent via a length of hair, but you've asked to deliver power.  There isn't a way to deliver enough power to operate a simple LED without burning up the hair.

To be honest, almost anything would work better.  Salt water would be my first choice.  Saliva would be mediocre, but it would work.  Blood would work better than human hair.  so would aqueous humor.  Even your skin would work better (under the correct conditions, you can hold a fluorescent tube in your hand and stand next to a wireless voltage source and the tube will light up).

But considering everything on the human body, the only thing that would work worse is finger and toe nails.

Answer (score 2):

## Neither:

Research shows:
Title: Physical properties of alpha-keratin fibers
Author: Feughelman, M

"with 7% water content have a resistivity 3 x 10^12 ohm-cm at room temperature"

This makes hair a **very** bad conductor, but an even **worse** insulator.
In addition, its electrical properties vary wildly depending on the humidity, health and age of the donor, their diet, etc. But none of the variations make for anything really usable.

The closest approximation to utility would be brine-soaked hair, which is a moderately bad conductor.
But cotton thread in the same state would be stronger, less prone to degradation, and conduct just as well/badly.

Instead, just use saltwater pipes. A simple brine has a resistance of about
2 ohm per m.
This is still pathetic, and nowhere near as good as copper (1.68x10^-8)
But it will suffice for sort distances.

Of greater concern is how to generate your electricity in the first place.
All of *our* electrical generation methods rely on magnetic inductance, in *metals*.
(some slight exceptions from eg. solar power. But that would still require metals for the conduction of very low voltages from the cells)

Besides.
If all metals are absent, just what are the plants and animals using to transport oxygen? There will be no copper for the chlorophyll, no iron for the hemoglobin.

Comment: Brine resistance can be *wanted*, as you could replace very very tiny resistors with it, or turn it into a thermosensor of sorts (the hotter, the less water, altering the resistance. Salt is not a conductor, but molten salt conducts well. And by the way: Carbon is a better conductor in the flat hexagonal design: Graphite.

Answer (score 1):

**Humans need a role in this future world.**

I propose that in your future, humans are largely irrelevant.  Artificial intelligences can do all the things humans used to do.  They are better engineers, better chefs, better governors, better mothers, better lovers.  Humans are cared for by their creations but biological humans are no longer essential.

But humans can grow hair.  Just as metals have been exhausted, so too our fellow vertebrates are gone.  Except for naked mole rats.  We are the only ones left with hair and so that is what we bring to the table.  Hair is used as the integral parts of machines - as conductors, resistors, capacitors, transistors, quantum dots; all hair.  Humans cultivate their hair for different uses - my hair might go to make microchips, while yours is better suited for tensile struts in air vehicles.  When I play a video game, I brag to my friends that some of the components were probably made using my hair.

The artificial intelligences know that hair is not the best thing for these applications.  But they were created to care for humanity and they know that humans need to feel needed, and so the use of hair technology continues.

This would, of course, be the kind of science fiction that is actually social commentary.

Comment: in this metal-free world, where do the AIs come from? Or how do the humans not die from lack of those silly Fe3+ in the Hem and Na+ in the neurons?

Comment: @Trish - you will need to edit this idea if you want it to be a metal free world.  Not sure where that came from but an interesting notion.